# Does datetime.datetime.now return cached values when called frequently?

Tags: python, python-datetime

I am using Python 3.7.6, with IPython 7.12.0

Code to replicate:

```
import datetime
mylist = []
for _ in range(10000):
    mylist.append(datetime.datetime.now())
```

Looking at `mylist`, I get chunks of about 2000 identical datetimes that are about 1ms apart. Because datetime.datetime objects have a resolution of 1µs, I should theoretically be getting chunks of 2 items that are 1µs apart instead.

What is happening here? Is the return value for datetime.datetime.now() cached for 1ms? If so, is this done on the Python side or the C side?

Comment: I don't see this with CPython 3.7.5.  I get `datetime.datetime` values that differ by 1µs or less.  Can you show some of the values you're seeing and provide more details about your environment?

Comment: I'm also skeptical that there would be any caching going on.  How would such a system know when to invalidate the cache?  And at that point, is there any point to caching?  I'm more inclined to believe that times are rounded to ms precision. (For example, modern web browsers reduce time precision to try to thwart timing-based, Spectre-like attacks.)

Comment: @jamesdlin there is no explicit rounding, `time.time()` has a resolution of ~1ms on Windows, I assume that's what OP is using. And I think that is an improvement and in the olden days it used to be something like 16ms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is happening here? Is the return value for datetime.datetime.now() cached for 1ms? If so, is this done on the Python side or the C side?

There is no caching involved. [As documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime%20now#datetime.datetime.now) `datetime.now` defers to `time.time` which is not a high-precision clock and (also as documented) may not even have sub-second resolution:

> Note that even though the time is always returned as a floating point number, not all systems provide time with a better precision than 1 second.

The resolution of `datetime.now` will therefore depend on the system it's run on and that system's configuration.

Assuming you are running on windows, [PEP 564](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0564/#windows) documented the resolution of `time.time()` as 894us, or 0.9ms, close enough to 1ms (for Windows 8).

You can use the alternative clocks it documents if you *need* higher resolution:

- `time.time_ns()` has a resolution of ~300us on Windows
- `perf_counter()` has a resolution of 100ns however **it does not return a timestamp**, so there's more work involved as you'll need to save a reference timestamp and perf_counter then use *these* in order to offset following perf counters and get actual timestamps.